# Как распечатать таблицу, которая будет выглядеть так:Subject Name | Subject Grade | Student Physical Education 100 Uzumaki Naruto

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from collections import deque

sname_list = ['Python', 'Math', 'Cisco']
grade_list = ['50', '45', '70']

name_q = deque(['Saskue', 'Naruto', 'Itachi'])

tup = sname_list, grade_list, name_q
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import deque

sname_list = ['Python', 'Math', 'Cisco']
grade_list = ['50', '45', '70']
name_q = deque(['Saskue', 'Naruto', 'Itachi'])

tup = sname_list, grade_list, name_q
print(tup)
# (['Python', 'Math', 'Cisco'], ['50', '45', '70'], deque(['Saskue', 'Naruto', 'Itachi']))

z = zip(sname_list, grade_list, name_q)
print(*z, sep='\n')

('Python', '50', 'Saskue')
('Math', '45', 'Naruto')
('Cisco', '70', 'Itachi')
```